# Is there a way to let the console in RStudio produce time stamps?

Tags: r, rstudio

Sometimes I wished there was some time stamp in the console of RStudio, e. g. to log when a process with unexpected long duration has been started.

```
> 13:08:45 head(data)
> 13:08:52 summary(data)
> ...
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: There is a function with the same name. Try `timestamp()` in your console.

Comment: Ah nice stuff, at least already a manually method to stamp the time into the console!

Comment: Thanks @Imo & @Stibu, I had not found that. @Iterator 's `tcltk2` package works fine for me.

Comment: This would be very useful for determining how long functions run for.